# How do I use VariableDefintions in a PowerShell interactive JEA session?

Tags: powershell, variables, powershell-remoting, remoting, jea

I've been trying to define variables for a PowerShell JEA session in configuration files using `VariableDefintions`.

However, access to the defined variables is denied. All other configurations with `VisibleCmdlets`, `FunctionDefinitions`, etc. are working.

```
VariableDefinitions @(
  @{ Name = 'Test'; Value = 'blah' }
}
```

After successfully entering the configured session interactively, I'm denied access to the defined variable from the console.

```
[remotehost]: PS> $Test

Cannot access the variable '$Test' because it is a private variable.
+ ----
   + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied (Test.String) [], SessionException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VariableIsPrivate
```

But since I've enabled FullLanguage mode, I am able to define variables to be used in an interactive session anyhow. So I'm using that as a work around.

Comment: The variable definitions are scoped to the underlying module, not the caller's remote session. So if you define and expose a script function that dereferences `$Test` without defining it locally first, it'll resolve the value `'blah'`, but you can't see it from the "facade" that the JEA endpoint exposes to you

Comment: So the behavior differs from `VisibleCmdlets` then? I suppose it would have been called `VisibleVariables` otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mathias is stating...

Variables defined using `VariableDefintions` in JEA are only available to specified functions and scripts.

Trying to access them from an interactive JEA console session is not possible.

Very good to use if I need to hide sensitive data.
Very sensitive data should of course be handled using `SecureString` when possible or a `SecretVault` system.